# How bad is to initialize a connection to MYSQL for every query?

Tags: c++, mysql, multithreading

I have an application that I was written and working on the past few years. The application works as a strategy mmo server side.
The application uses the MySql c++ connector.
As you know the MySql can not be used with one connection by more than one thread. So, although my application is multi-thread but it has been designed to work with MySql from one thread.
Now I've decided to cut some of the functionalists from the main thread and put them in another thread. In fact I'm gonna create new threads for some of the tasks.

I know that it could be a little weird and wrong, and also I know that I shouldn't create lot's of connections to the database, but what happen if I forget the connection pool and create a connection for every query?

Is there anybody that know what will happen to the server application if i do this?

Comment: it depends on how many queries you will fire on the server. but i got the feeling that it will be a lot and so i have to say 'dont do it'. make workers for your threads and let them handle their connections.

Comment: It was the first thing that I worked on. after a little bit of reviewing the application i got that I should change lot's of the application if i want to create limited connections and use them. there are lot's of singletones and proxy classes that changing them would force me to rewrite the whole application and i prefer to kill myself, forget the application or resign. :)

Comment: i think it was `extreme programming` where it was said that 'if you are afraid to change code, something is wrong' or like that ;)

Comment: Yeap, that's true. It goes back to my lack of knowledge or experience. :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know what you mean when you ask "*what will happen* to the server application if i [*sic*] do this", but I'm assuming you are worried about performance, so I'll try and answer that.

There's a two-part article about the effects of SSL encryption on MySQL performance over on "MySQL Performance Blog" (here's [part one](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/10/10/mysql-ssl-performance-overhead/) and [part two](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/11/18/mysql-encryption-performance-revisited/).) I suggest you give it a read.

The author is evaluating the performance overhead of using (built-in or otherwise) SSL encryption on MySQL query throughput and latency. This might not sound relevant, but as part of his benchmark, he also evaluates the effects of SSL on a program that is continually connecting to and disconnecting from the server as fast as possible.

By comparing the first chart in part 1 of the article (i.e. "Sysbench Read-Only - Throughput") with the third chart (i.e. "Connection Throughput") you'll see that repeatedly connecting to the server in a multithreaded environment will result in about **10x to 20x** (from 30K-50K to less than 3K) reduction in the number of queries performed per second.

Even the third chart alone can tell you a lot. According to that graph, if you create a new connection per query, you will only be able to perform less than 3000 queries per second *at the absolute maximum*.

This might help you calculate an upper bound on the performance of your game server. If you connect to the database for each and every query, even if you use a lot of threads, you will only be able to make three thousand connections. If you need (even theoretically) more than 3K queries per second, you *cannot* use this method. You'll need a connection pool or one connection per thread or something.

Two things to note:

- The 3K-connections-per-second number is when you do not do any queries at all. It you are actually performing queries, your number will be much worse.
- The website I've linked to is (I think) run by some Percona developers (which is a MySQL replacement/alternative.) The benchmark numbers look sensible to me, but you might want to draw your own conclusions.